# Javascript not including jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using this line of code to include a plugin by FlowPlayer.org.

```
<script type="text/javacript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

However, it's not working; the following says undefined:

```
alert(jQuery().tooltip);
```

jQuery **is** included.

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection? Just kiddin.. ;)

Comment: Yes Dave. It's working in other aspects of the site. I've tried it with another plugin too, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide some code, nobody is able to tell you what's wrong from given info.

Comment: If you do "Show code source" : 1/ you see `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`? 2/ you can read the code by clicking on it?

Comment: Possible problem might come from the order you reference the js files. jquery must be first, then the tools library. What happens when you get a local copy of the jquery/jquery.tools libraries instead of going through the cdn ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"text/javacript"` is not a valid value for `type` so the browser ignores the script.  You need `"text/javascript"` or better yet, just omit the type attribute entirely.

Comment: Never would've noticed that. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You must include [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) before using plugins.
Also, you must call tooltip() on some element, check demos http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** And if you type `alert(jQuery().tooltip());` instead of `alert(jQuery().tooltip);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You typed `javacript` on your declaration. Also, tooltip is a plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Download it here:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Anyway, a good way to check if your jQuery call is ok is to run `console.log(jQuery);` on your console to check if the result is valid.

Also, you can use this kind of approach to prevent errors:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="local/path/to/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```